# Visual Studio 2019 выдаёт многочисленные ошибки синтаксиса, не могу определить причину, особенно кавычку на 11 строчке перед она >"cmd"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Visual Studio 2019 выдаёт многочисленные ошибки синтаксиса, не могу определить причину, особенно кавычку на 11 строчке перед  она >"cmd"

```
import os
import time
import speech_recogniton as sr 
from fuzzywuzzy import fuss 
import pyttsx3
import datetime

opts = {
    "alias": ("ютубер", "ютьюбер", "ютебр", "ют", "ютер", "ёжка", "Utair" ),
    "tbr": ("скажи", "расскажи", "покажи", "сколько", "произнеси","проглаголь", "профиль", "включи", "режим", "запусти")
    "cmds":{
        "ctime": ("текущие время", "сейчас время", "который час", "которое время")
        "stuped":("расскажи анекдот", "рассмеши меня", "ты знаешь анекдот")
        "prof1":("хакера")
        "prof2":("игрока")
        "prof3":("ютубера")
        "prof4":("фотографа")
        "prog1":("браузер")
        "prog2":("steam")
        "prog3":("epic games")
        "prog4":("дискорд")
        "prog5":("проводник")
        "prog6":("саблайм текст")

    }   
}

#Функции

def speak(what):
    print ( what )
    speak_engine.say( what )
    speak_engine.runAndWait()
    speak_engine.stop()

def callback(recognize, audio):
    try:
        voice = recognize.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU").lower()
        print ("[log] Распознано: " + voice)

        if voice.startswith(opts["alias"]):
            #Обращение я ютуберу
            cmd = voice 

            for x in opts["alias"]:
                cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

            for x in opts["tbr"]:
                cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

            #Выполняем приказ

            cmd = recognize_cmd(cmd)
            execute_cmd(cmd["cmd"])

    expert sr.UnknownValueError:
        print ("[log] Голос не распознан!")
    expert sr.RequestError as e:
        print("[log] Неизвестная ошибка, проверьте соеденение с интернетом!")

def recognize_cmd(cmd):
    RC = {"cmd": "", percent: 0}
    for c, v in opts["cmds"].items():

        for x in v:
            vrt = fuzz.ratio(cmd, x)
            if vrt > RC["percent"]:
                RC["cmd"] = c 
                RC["percent"] = vrt

    return RC

def execute_cmd(cmd):
    if cmd == "ctime":
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        speak("Сейчас" + str(now.hour) + ":" + str (now.minute))

    elif == "stuped" :
        speak("Мой разработчик не научил меня шуткам... Ха ха ха")

    elif == "prof1" :
        os.system("X:\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe")
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera GX\\launcher.exe")
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\pythonw.exe")
        os.system("X:\\")

    elif == "prof2" :
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera GX\\launcher.exe")
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Discord\\Update.exe")
        os.system("X:\\Steam\\Steam.exe")
        os.system("X:\\Epic Games\\Launcher\\Portal\\Binaries\\Win32\\EpicGamesLauncher.exe")

    elif == "prof3" :
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera GX\\launcher.exe")
        os.system("X:\\obs-studio\\bin\\64bit\\obs64.exe")
        os.system("X:\\Adobe\\Adobe Premiere Pro 2020\\Adobe Premiere Pro.exe")
        os.system("X:\\Adobe\\Adobe Audition 2020\\Adobe Audition.exe")

    elif == "prof4" :
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera GX\\launcher.exe")
        os.system("X:\\Adobe\\Adobe Photoshop CC 2019\\Photoshop.exe")
        os.system("X:\\")

    elif == "prog1":
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera GX\\launcher.exe")

    elif == "prog2":
        os.system("X:\\Steam\\Steam.exe")

    elif == "prog3":
        os.system("X:\\Epic Games\\Launcher\\Portal\\Binaries\\Win32\\EpicGamesLauncher.exe")

    elif == "prog4":
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Discord\\Update.exe")

    elif == "prog5":
        os.system("X:\\")

    elif == "prog6":
        os.system("X:\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe")




#запуск ютубера

r = sr.Recognize()
m = sr.Microphone(device_index = 1)

with m as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

speak_engine = pyttsx3 


#Для доп голосов

voices = speak_engine.getProperty("voices")
speak_engine.setProperty("voice", voices[4].id)

speak("Добрый день, креэйтер" )
speak("Я слушаю")

stop_listing = r.listen_in_background (m, callback)
while True: time.sleap(0.1)
```

Comment: А где сами ерроры?

Comment: первая ковычкана 11 строчке

Comment: "запусти") запятая нужна после этого

Comment: Можешь написать как надо? я не до конца понимаю

Answer (score 3):

Не хватает запятой в предыдущей строке после `"запусти")`

А также после каждой строчки в `cmd: {}`

Answer (score 2):

Твоя ошибка одна из многих. Поправил что нашел

```py
import os
import time
import speech_recognition as sr 
from fuzzywuzzy import fuss 
import pyttsx3
import datetime

opts = {
    "alias": ("ютубер", "ютьюбер", "ютебр", "ют", "ютер", "ёжка", "Utair" ),
    "tbr": ("скажи", "расскажи", "покажи", "сколько", "произнеси","проглаголь", "профиль", "включи", "режим", "запусти"),
    "cmds":{
        "ctime": ("текущие время", "сейчас время", "который час", "которое время"),
        "stuped":("расскажи анекдот", "рассмеши меня", "ты знаешь анекдот"),
        "prof1":("хакера"),
        "prof2":("игрока"),
        "prof3":("ютубера"),
        "prof4":("фотографа"),
        "prog1":("браузер"),
        "prog2":("steam"),
        "prog3":("epic games"),
        "prog4":("дискорд"),
        "prog5":("проводник"),
        "prog6":("саблайм текст")

    }   
}

#Функции

def speak(what):
    print ( what )
    speak_engine.say( what )
    speak_engine.runAndWait()
    speak_engine.stop()

def callback(recognize, audio):
    try:
        voice = recognize.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU").lower()
        print ("[log] Распознано: " + voice)

        if voice.startswith(opts["alias"]):
            #Обращение я ютуберу
            cmd = voice 

            for x in opts["alias"]:
                cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

            for x in opts["tbr"]:
                cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

            #Выполняем приказ

            cmd = recognize_cmd(cmd)
            execute_cmd(cmd["cmd"])

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print ("[log] Голос не распознан!")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("[log] Неизвестная ошибка, проверьте соеденение с интернетом!")

def recognize_cmd(cmd):
    RC = {"cmd": "", percent: 0}
    for c, v in opts["cmds"].items():

        for x in v:
            vrt = fuzz.ratio(cmd, x)
            if vrt > RC["percent"]:
                RC["cmd"] = c 
                RC["percent"] = vrt

    return RC

def execute_cmd(cmd):
    if cmd == "ctime":
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        speak("Сейчас" + str(now.hour) + ":" + str (now.minute))

    elif cmd == "stuped" :
        speak("Мой разработчик не научил меня шуткам... Ха ха ха")

    elif cmd == "prof1" :
        os.system("X:\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe")
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera GX\\launcher.exe")
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\pythonw.exe")
        os.system("X:\\")

    elif cmd == "prof2" :
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera GX\\launcher.exe")
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Discord\\Update.exe")
        os.system("X:\\Steam\\Steam.exe")
        os.system("X:\\Epic Games\\Launcher\\Portal\\Binaries\\Win32\\EpicGamesLauncher.exe")

    elif cmd == "prof3" :
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera GX\\launcher.exe")
        os.system("X:\\obs-studio\\bin\\64bit\\obs64.exe")
        os.system("X:\\Adobe\\Adobe Premiere Pro 2020\\Adobe Premiere Pro.exe")
        os.system("X:\\Adobe\\Adobe Audition 2020\\Adobe Audition.exe")

    elif cmd == "prof4" :
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera GX\\launcher.exe")
        os.system("X:\\Adobe\\Adobe Photoshop CC 2019\\Photoshop.exe")
        os.system("X:\\")

    elif cmd == "prog1":
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera GX\\launcher.exe")

    elif cmd == "prog2":
        os.system("X:\\Steam\\Steam.exe")

    elif cmd == "prog3":
        os.system("X:\\Epic Games\\Launcher\\Portal\\Binaries\\Win32\\EpicGamesLauncher.exe")

    elif cmd == "prog4":
        os.system("C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Discord\\Update.exe")

    elif cmd == "prog5":
        os.system("X:\\")

    elif cmd == "prog6":
        os.system("X:\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe")




#запуск ютубера

r = sr.Recognize()
m = sr.Microphone(device_index = 1)

with m as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

speak_engine = pyttsx3 


#Для доп голосов

voices = speak_engine.getProperty("voices")
speak_engine.setProperty("voice", voices[4].id)

speak("Добрый день, креэйтер" )
speak("Я слушаю")

stop_listing = r.listen_in_background (m, callback)
while True: time.sleap(0.1)
```

Comment: Рекомендую использовать IDE PyCharm для разработки на Python